# Update Multiple Records without Checkbox

Tags: php, html

I need to update multiple records into a database on submit of a form. The form fields are repeating showing all the values but, the code doesn't seem to do anything. When someone hits submit, for each dataID presented in the hidden field, the progress and last_modified_date fields should be updated. I have googled and can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Here is the update code:

```
  if(isset($_POST['dataID'])){
    foreach($_POST['dataID'] as $updateid){
      $progress = $_POST['progress_'.$updateid];
      $last_modified_date = $_POST['last_modified_date_'.$updateid];
         $updateUser = "UPDATE data SET 
                      progress='".$progress."',last_modified_date='".$last_modified_date."' 
                      WHERE dataID=".$updateid;
         mysqli_query($sdpc_i,$updateUser);
      }
  }

}
?><form method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select title="progress" name="progress[]" id="progress" class="form-control form-control-sm-3">
                  <option selected value="">Select One</option>
                  <option value="Contract Sent">Contract Sent</option>
                  <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
                  <option value="With Legal">With Legal</option>
                  <option value="Declined">Declined</option>
                  <option value="Vendor Unresponsive">Vendor Unresponsive</option>
                  <option value="Approved/No Data Collected">Approved/No Data Collected</option>
                </select>
 <?php
while(!$district_results_private->atEnd()) {
?>
              <input name="dataID[]" type="text" id="dataID" value="<?php echo($district_results_private->getColumnVal("dataID")); ?>" />
              <?php
  $district_results_private->moveNext();
}
$district_results_private->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
?>
<input name="last_modified_date[]" type="hidden" id="last_modified_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
 <input type="image" src="images/save.png" name="submit" id="submit" alt="Save" />
        </form>

--------------------------------------------
UPDATE:

Thank you so much for your help! I did what you said and I am still getting these errors. 

Notice: Undefined index: progress in /var/www/html/progress_workflow_multiple3.php on line 97

Notice: Undefined index: dataID in /var/www/html/progress_workflow_multiple3.php on line 98

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/progress_workflow_multiple3.php on line 98


Here is the code I have: 

<?php
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($sdpc_i);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "UPDATE data SET progress = ?, last_modified_date = CURDATE() WHERE dataID = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $progress, $dataID);
$progress = $_POST['progress'];
foreach ($_POST['dataID'] as $dataID) {
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
?> 


Here is the form code: 

<label for="progress"></label>
              <span class="small_links">
                <select title="progress" name="progress" id="progress" class="form-control form-control-sm-3">
                  <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option>Contract Sent</option>
    <option>Approved</option>
    <option>With Legal</option>
    <option>Declined</option>
    <option>Vendor Unresponsive</option>
    <option>Approved/No Data Collected</option>
                </select>
              </span>
            <div id="div1"></div>
            <div id="div2"></div>
            <div id="div3"></div>
            <?php
while(!$district_results_private->atEnd()) {
    ?>
    <input name="dataID[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $district_results_private->getColumnVal("dataID"); ?>" />
    <?php
    $district_results_private->moveNext();
}
$district_results_private->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
?>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>
          <input type="image" src="images/save.png" name="submit" id="submit" alt="Save" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Except for `dataID` all of your `POST` vars are array's with `1` value, you should acces them by using `$_POST['progress'][0]`.

Comment: Your code is highly vulnarable to attacks. It's vulnerable to sql injection, xss and csrf

Comment: Should I change it to this? <?php
$dataID = $_POST['dataID'];
$explode_on_colon = explode(":",$dataID);
$copy = count($dataID); //not sure why you called it copy though

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  for($i=0;$i<$copy;$i++)
{

      $progress = $_POST['progress_'.$updateid];
      $last_modified_date = $_POST['last_modified_date_'.$updateid];
         $updateUser = "UPDATE data SET 
                      progress='".$progress."',last_modified_date='".$last_modified_date."' 
                      WHERE dataID=".$updateid;
         mysqli_query($sdpc_i,$updateUser);
}

}
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form has 3 essential parts (excluding the submit of course) for the user to interact with:

- `<select id="progress">` ...(progress field)
- `<input id="dataID">` ...(dataId fields) this may occur multiple times
- `<input id="last_modified_date">` ...(lastMod field)

The progress field will only occur once, so there is no benefit in structuring its data as an array.  Furthermore, a select field will default to its first option, so there is no need for `selected` on the first option. Also, when the `value` value of an option is exactly the same as the option's text, you can safely omit the `value` attribute.

```
<select title="progress" name="progress" class="form-control form-control-sm-3">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option>Contract Sent</option>
    <option>Approved</option>
    <option>With Legal</option>
    <option>Declined</option>
    <option>Vendor Unresponsive</option>
    <option>Approved/No Data Collected</option>
</select>
```

The dataId fields are rightly given an array-type `name`. However, it is inappropriate to assign multiple elements with the same `id` attribute.  If you application is not using the `id` attributes (for any fields), just omit the declaration(s).  If you need to assign unique `id` attributes, you will need to provide an incrementing counter and append that counter to the end of the `id` value.

```
while(!$district_results_private->atEnd()) {
    ?>
    <input name="dataID[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $district_results_private->getColumnVal("dataID"); ?>" />
    <?php
    $district_results_private->moveNext();
}
```

The lastMod field can be completely omitted from the document. You are always passing the current date with the submission and don't want the user fiddling with it -- good news, you can hardcode that directly into your sql and the user won't be able to touch it.

As for the UPDATE queries, best practice indicates that you should be implementing a prepared statement and binding dynamic values to it in a loop for security and stability.

(Untested -- I never use procedural syntax)

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($sdpc_i);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "UPDATE data SET progress = ?, last_modified_date = CURDATE() WHERE dataID = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $progress, $dataID);
$progress = $_POST['progress'];
foreach ($_POST['dataID'] as $dataID) {
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

p.s. I hope that `data` isn't your *real* table name -- because it is bad/imprecise/non-descriptive.  Name it something intuitive/logical/expressive.

Comment: It may be easiest to show me a 3v4l.org demo link of your latest code and type the exact error as a comment.  I'm in bed now, so I might not respond until morning.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have added an update to the bottom of my post with the new issues. Thanks

Comment: You still need to check that the form is submitted with `if(isset($_POST['dataID'])){` (or any submission check). Or else it will try to save when there is no submission yet (first page load).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I have never used 3v4l.org but, I am happy to do this. :)

Comment: I assume you need something like this: https://3v4l.org/tFfCp  When I have resolved your issue, you can [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/352329). Until it is resolved, please clarify where you are stuck so that I can progress the page toward resolution.

Comment: OMG! It worked. You are awesome. I can't thank you enough! :)